# Google earth api javascript control

Tags: javascript, html, google-earth-plugin, google-street-view

I have an HTML file in which the camera flies from space to a street view and I only need to move forward, in a random direction to the next streetview and keep moving. Just like keeping the up arrow pressed. Does anyone know how to do it, please? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible, the Google Earth Api (to date) does not expose any methods to control the street-view mode other that enabling/disabling. All movement is via user input rather than programmatic control.

That said, it may just be possible to kludge this by simulating key presses using something like jQuery.

[Is it possible to simulate key press events programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596481/simulate-javascript-key-events/596580#596580)